# Per thread singleton pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, singleton

In my work I stumbled upon such a design issue:

- I need one instance of a `Manager` class per thread
- These instances should be globally accessible, like in the singleton pattern via a static function
- Each thread might need to initialize its instance with different arguments
- The lifetime of these instances should be controllable, sometimes it would be beneficiary to remove an instance and allow GC to collect it

The first two points would make it a 'per thread singleton' if such a thing exists.

This is what I came up with (the code is simplified, I've omitted safety checks and so on):

```
public class Manager {
  private final static ThreadLocal<Manager> local = new ThreadLocal<Manager>();

  private int x;
  Manager(int argument) { x = argument; }

  public static void start(int argument) { local.set(new Manager(argument); }
  public static void clean() { local.remove(); }

  private void doSomething1() { x++; .... }
  private int doSomething2() { if (--x == 0) clean(); ... }

  public static void function1() { local.get().doSomething1(); }
  public static int function2() { return local.get().doSomething2(); }
}
```

As you can see the clean function can be also called from within the private methods.
Also notice that through the use of static functions the reference to the instance is never leaked, so instances assigned to different threads won't get mixed.

This works quite ok, but then I got another requirement:

- Different threads may need to utilize different implementations of Manager class

So I defined an interface:

```
public interface ManagerHandler {
  void method1();
  int method2();
}
```

And modified the `Manager` class:

```
public class Manager {
  private final static ThreadLocal<ManagerHandler> local = new ThreadLocal<ManagerHandler>();

  public static void start(int argument) {
    ManagerHandler handler;
    // depending on the context initialize handler to whatever class it is necessary
    local.set(handler); 
  }
  public static void clean() { local.remove(); }

  public static void function1() { local.get().method1(); }
  public static int function2() { return local.get().method2(); }
}
```

An example implementation would look like this:

```
public class ExampleManagerImplementation implements ManagerHandler {
  private int x;
  public ExampleManagerImplementation(int argument) { x = argument; }
  public void method1() { x++; .... }
  public int method2() { if (--x == 0) Manager.clean(); ... }
}
```

Manager class works here as a facade, forwarding all the calls to the appropriate handler. There is one big issue with this approach: I need to define all the functions both in the `Manager` class and in the `ManagerHandler` interface. Unfurtunately `Manager` class can't implement `ManagerHandler` interface, because it has static functions rather than methods.

The question is: can you think of a better/easier way to accomplish all the goals I've listed above that would be free of this issue?

Comment: (I am forced to comment that this brings so many bad things together. A "Manager" is usually a bad sign. "Manager" without any kind of indication what it is managing in the name. A static reference to an effectively mutable object. A mutable static reference. A non-private mutable field. Thread locals.)

Comment: The code is simplified. The real name of the class is not just 'Manager', of course it indicates what it is about ;) I can add private access modifier and final if you want. But what's wrong with thread locals and a static reference to a mutable object (which is thread-safe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do, as you basically need to proxy interface methods through static methods. I could only think of two ways to achieve the same functionality differently:

1. If you're using a DI framework, you can get rid of the static `Manager` and use an injected implementation of `ManagerHandler` which will contain the `ThreadLocal`.
2. Generate (as in 'bytecode generation') the static `ManagerAccess` class using the methods found in the `ManagerHandler` interface.

Personally, I wouldn't think of having the static `ManagerAccess` class (which contains the `ThreadLocal`) around as a serious design issue. At least as long as it keeps to its own set of responsibilities (accessing thread-scoped instances and proxying calls) and doesn't venture anywhere else.

Comment: I guess there is nothing more to say in this topic. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going with this design, is it necessary for `Manager` to totally hide `ManagerHandler` interface, or could you expose it so you don't have to delegate every method?

```
class Manager {
    public static ManagerHandler getHandler() { return local.get(); }
}
```

Comment: I've considered this as well, but I'd prefer to have it hidden, so that references to the instances are not leaked and each thread can only access the right object

Answer (score -1):

The trick for creating a singleton per thread class is to use [ThreadStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute on your private static _current field which makes it scoped by thread. In this way, the _current field will be stored inside thread memory which is not accessible for the other threads and not shared memory of AppDomain. So, it will be available only in the scope of the thread. On the other hand, the Current property is accessible across all threads in that AppDomain but when it is called it will return the correct instance for that thread. Here is the code that you need:

```
public sealed class Manager
{
    // As you are using the ThreadStatic here you cannot
    // call the static constructor or use the Lazy implimentation for 
    // thread-safty and you have to use the old fashin Lock and anti-pattern.
    private static readonly object _criticalArea = new object();

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Manager _current;
    public static Manager Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
            {
                lock (_criticalArea)
                {
                    if (_current == null)
                    {
                        _current = new Manager();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _current;
        }
    }

    private Manager()
    {
    }

    public string WhatThreadIsThis { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class SingeltonPerThreadTest
{
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _threadHandler = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    private string _sharedMemory = "I am the shared memory and yet in main thread :(";

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSingeltonPerThread()
    {
        // Creates a _current for main thread.
        Manager.Current.WhatThreadIsThis = "I am the main thread :)";

        // Start another thread.
        (new Thread(CallTheThreadBaseSingelton)).Start();

        // Wait for it to be finished.
        _threadHandler.WaitOne();

        Assert.AreEqual("I am the main thread :)", Manager.Current.WhatThreadIsThis, "I am not the main thread :( ");
        Assert.AreEqual("I am the other thread ;)", _sharedMemory, _sharedMemory);
    }

    private void CallTheThreadBaseSingelton()
    {
        // Creates a _current for this thread (this thread is the other one :)) ).
        Manager.Current.WhatThreadIsThis = "I am the other thread ;)";
        _sharedMemory = Manager.Current.WhatThreadIsThis;
        _threadHandler.Set();
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: This post is tagged as Java, this is a C# answer.